# If Maven release:prepare fails, how to continue from the failed point?

Tags: maven-2, maven-release-plugin

Can anyone please suggest how to continue the maven release:prepare from the point which failed?

I tried with the resume command, but it does not continue from the failed point.

Answer (score 7):

Quote from the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html):

> If an error occurs, or the process is cancelled, then running this
>   command again will pick up from where the last one left off.

So, just run `mvn release:prepare` again.

Answer (score 2):

Is it feasible for you to start over with preparing and performing the release?

Then you could try `mvn release:rollback`.

If that doesnt work, delete the new files that were created, `pom.xml.releasBackup` and `release.properties` and try over.

Comment: is there any other arguments can be used to start from the failed point?

Comment: the only release goals I can see are: branch, clean, help, perform, prepare, prepare-with-pom, rollback, stage, update-versions. In other words, as far as I can see - no. In any case if it fails I would feel *much* more comfortable with rolling back the release, resolving the error if you can find it, and trying again.

Comment: In our org the network to maven repository is flaky, so during the release, publishing the artifact may fail (network issues). There is no retry mechanism on that task, so we have to just rollback and re-release - would be better to just continue from the last successful step

Answer (score 1):

Our release failed on the very last module. Here's what the logs said:

`[INFO] [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[INFO] [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :module-that-failed`

That might not work for release:prepare - but running 'mvn release:prepare' just started over from the beginning.